# How can I keep an element within the visible area while growing as much as possible and keeping the aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, viewport

I am trying to create a simple image gallery thing, but I'm having trouble with the following:

- the `slide-img` should be as big as possible, but it must always keep its aspect ratio
- the whole thing should be centered both vertically and horizontally, and it should always be completely within the visible area (so no scrolling)
- the `preview-column`s should all be horizontally centered with a uniform distance between them as opposed to stretching.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with this here. I have attached a simplified MWE example.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

```html
<html>
    <style>
        .modal {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            margin: 10%;
        }        
        .slideshow {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: rebeccapurple;
        }        
        .arrow-left, .arrow-right {
            position: absolute;
            background: green;
        }        
        .arrow-left {
            left: 0;
        }        
        .arrow-right {
            right: 0;
        }        
        .preview {
            display: flex;
            justify-items: center;
            max-height: 100px;
        }        
        .preview-column {
            background-color: dodgerblue;
        }        
        .preview-img {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            object-fit: contain;
        }        
        .slide {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: brown;
        }        
        .slide-img {
            object-fit: contain;
            background-color: khaki;
        }        
        .info {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            color: white;
            background-color: lightpink;
        }        
        .counter {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            color: white;
            background-color: mediumturquoise;
        }
    </style>          
    <body>
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="slideshow">
                <div class="slide">
                    <img class="slide-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
                    <p class="counter">1/42</p>
                    <p class="info">Image Caption</p>
                    <div class="arrow-left">Left</div>
                    <div class="arrow-right">Right</div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="preview">
                    <div class="preview-column">
                        <img class="preview-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
                    </div>
                    <div class="preview-column">
                        <img class="preview-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
                    </div>
                    <div class="preview-column">
                        <img class="preview-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
                    </div>
                    <div class="preview-column">
                        <img class="preview-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```